# version 'libcrypto.so.10' not found

Tags: ubuntu, centos, openssl

I am trying to run an executable that makes use of the libcrypto and libsll libraries. When I run the executable I get the following error

```
PROGRAM: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I understand that the above message is because the executable cannot find the associated library. The system has both pairs of libraries included in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", which I installed using the synaptic package manager. I have tried to generate the symbolic links

```
   ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10
   ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10
   ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10
```

but in all these cases I get the following error message:

```
PROGRAM: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by PROGRAM)
```

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.0, and the executable I am trying to use was compiled for RHEL 6.6. My question is: Should I install RHEL (or centOS) to be able to use that executable?, or, the error is due to the fact that I am using the wrong version of the libraries.

Comment: You need to have an [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)-compatible version of the library: same version number or close, and for some libraries (I don't know if that applies to OpenSSL) compiled with the same settings. Using different version will at best not work (as you saw) or at worst crash or result in corrupted data. Evidently RHEL/CentOS has its own numbering scheme for OpenSSL since it uses version=10 for a build of OpenSSL 1.something. You can try copying `libcrypto.so.10` from CentOS into a custom path and using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: It may be easier to create a CentOS schroot than to find the right version of libraries. [You can use schroot for that](https://oar.imag.fr/wiki:schroot-centos).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried with the RHEL libraries and it raised problems with other dependencies. Finally I had to install centOS 8 and subsequently  "sudo dnf install compat-openssl10", which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum reinstall openssl-libs
yum update openssh-clients
```

Run these commands and you will solve it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think this approach will solve the OPs problem.